# Keras: how to deal with unbalanced classes in sematic segmentation task?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I have pretrained VGG16 based FCN-32s like model, defined like:

```python
def pop_layer(model):
    if not model.outputs:
        raise Exception('Sequential model cannot be popped: model is empty.')

    model.layers.pop()
    if not model.layers:
        model.outputs = []
        model.inbound_nodes = []
        model.outbound_nodes = []
    else:
        model.layers[-1].outbound_nodes = []
        model.outputs = [model.layers[-1].output]
    model.built = False

def get_model():
    #Fully convolutional part of VGG16
    model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

    #Remove last max pooling layer
    pop_layer(model)

    #Freeze pretrained layers
    for layer in model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    model = Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=model.outputs)

    #print('len(model.layers)', len(model.layers)) #
    #print(model.summary()) #

    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(model.output)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(NUMBER_OF_CLASSES, kernel_size=(32, 32), strides=(16, 16), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
    head = Reshape((-1,NUMBER_OF_CLASSES))(x)

    model = Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=head)

    model.compile(optimizer=Adadelta(), loss='binary_crossentropy')

    print('len(model.layers)', len(model.layers)) #
    print(model.summary()) #

    return model
```

Model summary:

```python
len(model.layers) 21
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, None, None, 3)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 64)    1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 64)    36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 64)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 128)   73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 128)   147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 128)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 256)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 512)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTr (None, None, None, 3)     1572867   
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, None, 3)           0         
=================================================================
Total params: 18,647,363
Trainable params: 3,932,675
Non-trainable params: 14,714,688
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

But when I train model it only predict most dominant class, my dataset is unbalanced:

```python
Pixel area per class ratio:
class1 : 62.93 %
class2 : 25.46 %
class3 : 11.61 %
```

So my questions are: is my model definition ok? How to deal with class inbalanced? maybe batch should be constructed in some special way?

Comment: I have the same problem. did it work for your case considering each class as a binary problem and using binary crossentropy?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your loss doesn't fit your problem. You use binary cross entropy loss here:

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adadelta(), loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

But you have more than two classes. So I would suggest to use `categorical_crossentropy` loss (appears in the list of losses [here](https://keras.io/losses/). Read on the bottom of the page how to prepare your data in order to use this loss).

There are additional types of losses which may fit better inbalance classes situation. You may try to use dice loss, which is a differential approximation of IoU (intersection over union).

This loss is described on page 6, section 3 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.04797.pdf%E2%80%8B).

Comment: I now about `softmax + categorical_crossentropy`, but my markup data can have multiply labels per pixel, so I want to use `sigmoid + binary_crossentropy`, so I want to consider each output 'plane' as binary problem (class and background), but I'm not sure I'm defined it right. Also dice is defined for binary class problem only, I'm not sure how to generalize it to N classes. Also here is some simple example https://github.com/mrgloom/keras-semantic-segmentation-example of different cases.

Comment: Also I have tried `softmax + categorical_crossentropy` and it predicts also only most dominant class.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to use class weighing for the loss function, so you can penalize the effect of the prominent class.
weight_class = 1/ln(c + class_probability)
where c is a constant and mostly used value 1.03.